# Oracle Backup and Recovery Issue

Tags: oracle, backup, recovery, restore

I have backed up database located on **Host1** and restored/recovered it on **Host2**. 
After a while, I backed up DB on **Host1** again.

Now I want DBs on **Host1** and **Host2** be the same using last backup.

How can I achieve this? Without deleting database on **Host2**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to just do a restore/recover over top of the existing Host2.  If you are trying to avoid a complete recovery, then I suspect the answer is **you can't**, but there are two notable exceptions.

1. If you never opened the database on Host2 and you have all the archive logs between the first backup and the second, then you can recover Host2 using them.
2. If you have opened Host2, you still might be able to do this if you have flashback database enabled and can flash back to the point before you opened it.

Comment: During first variant.. I need what?
all archivelogs and newly backuped conrolfile? Or I just register newly backuped archivelogs with old control file and recover ?

Am I wrong?

Comment: Just recover.  See http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/backup.112/e10642/osrecvry.htm#CHDGFAFB.

Comment: Assuming these are os files a simple restore would work, but if your using ASM you will need to take care of the original files as new ones will be created. The original ones will just take up space and make removing them a little harder later on.